# GRPC Service Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, protocol-buffers, grpc

Is it possible for a gRPC service to inherit from another?

Say I have the service:

```
service Foo {
  rpc FooCallOne(FooRequestOne) returns (FooResponseOne);
  rpc FooCallTwo(FooRequestTwo) returns (FooResponseTwo);
}
```

And I want to create a `service Bar` such that it implements all services from `service Foo`. Is this possible within the proto file?

If not, what would people suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no service inheritance in protobuf.

Instead, you can have a comment in `service Bar` saying to use `service Foo` for its operations. That means that `service Foo` will probably need to coordinate between the various other services, especially if you have a `service Baz` that also "inherits" `service Foo`.

The only other alternative is to copy the methods, at which point they become *new, distinct* methods and share no relation to `service Foo`.

Comment: I ended up writing my own "compiler" for ZeroMQ :P